# How to merge stream using StreamZip in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two streams:

```
Stream<List<Order>>  stream1 = pendingStream();
Stream<List<Order>>  stream2 = preparingStream();
```

I'm trying to use `StreamZip` from the  `package:async/async.dart` package to merge the streams like so...

```
Stream<List<Order>> getData() {
     Stream<List<Order>>  stream1 = pendingStream();
     Stream<List<Order>>  stream2 = preparingStream();
    return StreamZip([stream1, stream2]);
}
```

However it won't compile. Saying:

```
The element type 'Stream<List<Order>>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Stream<Order>'.
```

From what I understand StreamZip should accept the two streams? What am I dong wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a `StreamZip<T>` which will emit a `List<T>` of each event of its merged streams as you can [refer in the documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/async/latest/async/StreamZip-class.html).

Each of your merged streams emit a `List<Order>` type, so that means that you will create a merged stream that will emit a `List` of `List`.

Basically, you only need to change your return type from `Stream<List<Order>>` to `Stream<List<List<Order>>>`.