# Get data from two collections - Firebase/Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have got a question for my app. I have two collections which are called X and Y. I need to get data from specific field from those collections. "X" and "Y" collections have the same field like  "name". I have been trying to get the names from X and Y collections and list them on my page. My codes:

```
 getNames(myId) async{

    return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("X").where('ID',isEqualTo: myId ).snapshots();
  }
```

I can get the name from X collection and list them on my page with this code. But I couldn't get the Y collections name at the same time with X and list them on my page.
Thanks for your interest and help in advance.

Comment: If you have two collections, you need two queries.  Firestore will not query across multiple collections except for [collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries), which work across all collections of the same name.  It's up to you to make both of those queries separately, then combine the results in your app code.  Either that, or combine all the data in a single collection and perhaps use a discriminating field to discern X from Y.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thanks for answering. I got what you meant. The second options which is combining all the data in a single collection would make the app so complicated. Id choose the first option, Ive tried it but could not achieve what I wanted. Like  

await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("X").where('ID',isEqualTo: myId ).snapshots();
return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Y").where('ID',isEqualTo: myId ).snapshots();
 when I do so, I just see the name from Y collection. If you helped me Id be glad.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem than what you have here - please post a new question for that if you're stuck on combining everything in a single collection.

Comment: I'm not trying to combine them in a single collection. Just trying to post the same field from different collections on my page

Comment: I'm sure you can find information on combining two streams in dart if you do a web search for that.

Comment: Thanks, I'm searching, that's what I need exactly.

Comment: rather than having `X` and `Y` collections, make them documents of single collection, so you can fetch them in one go, fields exists in a document not collection,

Answer (score 0):

```
  getNames(myId) async{  
    QuerySnapshot response1  = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("X").where('ID',isEqualTo: myId ).get();
    QuerySnapshot response2 = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Y").where('ID',isEqualTo: myId ).get();
    List<DocumentSnapshot> list1 = response1.docs;
    list1.addAll(response2.docs);
    return list1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Stream<QuerySnapshot>stream1 = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("X").where('ID',isEqualTo: myId ).snapshots();
Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream2 = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Y").where('ID',isEqualTo: myId ).snapshots();
  how to combine two streams here?
    return ....;

Comment: I am really sorry I gave you a wrong code, I just edited my answer it should work fine now if you have any problem with it just tell me. Sorry again.

Comment: return StreamZip(([stream1, stream2])).asBroadcastStream();
StreamZip doesn't work for it

Comment: I am sorry I am not familiar with this streamzip but this could help maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62955391/how-to-merge-stream-using-streamzip-in-dart

Comment: addAll gives an error which says "this expression has a type of void so its value can't be used"

Comment: Oh yeah my bad, sorry again, please just remove the declaration of list2 and it will solve the error ( I edited my answer )